# Android studio SDK error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a issues with my Android Studio,it works normally but after some Windows upgrade it stops working,it can't build the project. Android Studio send me a message that I missing SDK and that he can't locate adb.I will post image of problem,so You can see that I have latest version of Android Studio and SDK tools and I tried everything,reinstall program many times but nothing happens. [image: This is image of that error]

Comment: The error message and the solution is described right there; why does re-installation fail? You don't have the latest version of the SDK tools if it is asking you to install v24.0.2.

Comment: You need to check your setting under _Android SDK_

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**
`File>Invalidate cache>Invalidate and Restart`.
If that doesn't work for you, close your current project and open another older project(either yours or something from github) which has a lower api level than your project and build it.After that close it and go back to your current project. I don't know how but this works for me.